# Initializing a member vector<vector<int>> in the constructor value-by-value

Tags: c++, variables, visual-studio-2015, member

I have a class that should generate a 2D vector of ints (in the range of 0-1) that I want to use as a map (called matrix).

```
    class generator
    {
    public:
        void draw(void);
        void iterate(void);
        generator();
        ~generator();
    private:
        vector<vector<int>> matrix;
    };
```

In the constructor I want to fill the matrix with random data:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(height, vector<int>(width));
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = rand() % 2;
    }
}
```

But I get a read acess violation.
Thank you for your time and effort.

DEPRECATED UPDATE:
I tried using the member function .data() to retrieve the pointer to the data and accessing it directly

```
ptr = matrix[i][j].data();
*ptr = rand() % 2;
```

But the result doesn't differ. I'm fairly convinced that this isn't about how I want to access the vector but how I set it up.

UPDATE 2:

The correction provided below does result in the vector being filled as intended. When trying to

```
cout << matrix[i][j];
```

in the draw member function I get a read-acess-violation again.

UPDATE 3:

As suggested I checked when exactly this error happens. It happens on the very first try do print out the first integer at matrix[0][0]. The value returned is 0x8. Important: If not replaced by a constant matrix.size() already causes the error.

UPDATE 4:

This is basically my draw()

```
void generator::draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The original source has been updated to reflect the current one.

UPDATE 4:
Slightly cut source code at http://pastebin.com/83vrDJWZ

UPDATE 5:
One more simple mistake on my part has been resolved in the comments. Problem is silved. Thank you all.

Comment: Since you've tagged VisualStudio I'd strongly recommend looking at the code with a debugger - see for what `i,j` it fails. Best bet is you're asking for an element outside the boundaries of the vector (i.e. `j` variable is not less than inner vectors' supposed size).

Comment: Two suggestions. Don't use .data() function on vectors, and try to do the very same thing during the matrix setup - print the data you've just filled in.

Comment: Naive question: in the constructor, do you assign to this->matrix, or do you create a local variable? (still though draw() shouldn't fail, as the matrix woud be 0x0). [I removed the comment about the generator function, as I did not notice you meant it's done in ctor]

Comment: @hauron the provided code of the constructor is all that is relevant to the vector. I was under the impression that I was not creating a local variable even though I'm not assigning this->matrix.

Comment: Simple check: alter the line: `vector<vector<int>> matrix(height, vector<int>(width));` to: `matrix = vector<vector<int>>(height, vector<int>(width));`

Comment: @haudron the problem persist. `matrix.size()` results in an error, if replaced by a constant (10 e.g.) `cout << matrix[0][0];` results in it

Comment: I apologize but from the code and your responses I cannot think of another reason why this should fail, maybe apart from wild guesses. I'd recommend either: reformat the code or paste it onto ideone.com: smallest, compilable example reproducing your issue, or fight with the debugger.

Comment: @haudron thanks for your time. added a pastebin link.

Comment: found the issue: line 79 or 81, you never assign to `g` from line 77, but instead another variable shadowing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is an invalid pointer due to:

```
vector<vector<int>*> matrix;
```

You have a vector of pointers to vector of int, but you never actually allocate the inner elements.

Instead use:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix;
```

And during the initialization steps:

```
matrix[i].resize(width); // instead of: matrix[i]->resize(width);
```

Actually, you could simplify it a bit:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(height, std::vector<int>(width));
```

Still have to iterate to fill the data, though.